# Why the 'date_query' is not working in 'pre_get_posts' hook?

Tags: pre-get-posts, date-query

I need to output popular posts in a blog using several params:

- Not older than one week;
- Rating is over than 250;
- Order by date

Here is my code:

```
function evanre_custom_order_query( $query ) {

  if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
    return;
  }

  $query_var_show = get_query_var( 'show' );

  if ( empty( $query_var_show ) ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( 'popular' === $query_var_show ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
      array(
        'key'     => 'blt_upvotes',
        'value'   => 250,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
      ),
    ) );
    $query->set( 'date_query ', array(
      array(
        'after' => '1 week ago'
      )
    ) );
  }

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'evanre_custom_order_query' );
```

My custom query_var is registered and working. Ordering by date works, meta_query works too. date_query is completely ignored. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got trailing space in your `$query->set()`.

Instead of

```
$query->set( 'date_query ', ...
```

it should be:

```
$query->set( 'date_query', ...
```

Comment: Hawk-eyed detection there ;-)

Comment: @birgire technically, in my case, it's "[Kestrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_kestrel#Taxonomy)-eyed" :-)

Comment: hehe it looks like the "bugs" don't stand a change against the Kestrel's hunting technique ;-)